# Is there any event reciver available for user group events?

Tags: groups, event-receivers, user

I have to update some list whenever a new user or group is added to the site.

Is there any event receiver available for users/groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no event receiver for users or user groups. So you'll have to create a timer job and do the checking for new groups yourselvers.

Or you can add some javascript to a delegate control (AdditionalPageHead) which checks for the current page being _layouts/newgrp.aspx and if it is hooks the clicked event of ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl06_RptControls_btnOK to fire off an AjaxCall to your code.

Comment: Which button id it is "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl06_RptControls_btnOK" Also i am not going to add the user group through UI. Doing through code.

Comment: That button id is the create button on the newgrp page, but I admit it's a hack to use. It's only if you need to run your code fast when a group is created through the UI. If you create the groups using code, then why not run your code in there or add a SPWorkItem for a timer job you create.

Answer (score 1):

You have to donwload the SharePoint 2010 Event Manager, then in the user Assign your Assymbly(Event Receiver) to the **User Information List** of your site and Test!!